# How to make header menu smooth scroll if header is common?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-menu").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            id = $(this).data('id');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I have a common header where smooth scroll working only when if I am on `index` page because I am define `id` on index page. Now, I want if I am on another page but when I click any id of header then it redirect to index and open related `id` section. So, How can I do that? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: where you add this jQuery code. It's in all the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other page when click on menu item redirect to index page and send clicked data attribute id with url. When you get id from url trigger click event.
Like.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var hash = location.hash.substr(1).split('-');
        var id= hash[1];
        if(id && hash[0] == 'clicked'){
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.nav-menu[data-id="'+id+'"]').trigger('click')}, 5);

        }
        $(".nav-menu").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            id = $(this).data('id');
            if ($("#"+id).length){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }else{
                window.location.href="index?#clicked-"+id;
            }
        });
});
```